# input tag in react not letting enter more than one character when array of inputs are rendered in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not able to enter more than one character in the input type="text" element in react.

After first character, the react app is rerendering preventing me to enter another character.Please let me know what i am missing here.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shape-6ohjk?file=/src/ProductContainer.js)

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what you're trying to achieve or a code example that shows what you are doing.

Comment: Updated the sandbox with minimalistic code. All I want is to enter data with multiple characters in the input field. It's letting me enter only one character.

Comment: check `onChange={onChangeQuantityHandler}` in productview.js... expanding something so simple into something so elaborate and wide.... that's all i could tell u(im hungry)

Comment: I have an array of input fields that is the major problem . If i want to update only one input field , its straightforward just e.target.value in the state variable and use that state variable as the value for  input field.  I need to update the array of object which is productData state. Once i update it, it rerenders with the update value on in the input field where i added the text.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `key` value, which you are setting to `uuid()`.  Every time the component re-renders you generate a new UUID, which creates a brand new input.  You can see it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fire-c4if8?file=/src/ProductView.js) using the index as the key instead.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { InnerWrapper, Heading } from "./styling";
import uuid from "react-uuid";

export const ProductView = (props) => {
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState(props.productData);

  const updateProductData = (newQuantity = undefined, index = "") => {
    const _ = productData.map((data, idx) => {
      if (idx === index) {
        return {
          ...data,
          quantity: newQuantity ? newQuantity : data.quantity
        };
      } else {
        return { ...data };
      }
    });
    setProductData(_);
  };

  const onChangeQuantityHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newQuantity = parseInt(e.target.value.trim());
    const index = parseInt(e.target.dataset.index);
    updateProductData(newQuantity, index);
  };

  return (
    <InnerWrapper flexDirection="column">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Quantity </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {productData.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
              <tr key={idx}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    value={data.quantity}
                    name="quantity"
                    data-index={idx}
                    onChange={onChangeQuantityHandler}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </InnerWrapper>
  );
};
```

If you truly want to use a UUID as the key, I suggest you generate one beforehand.

Comment: Thank You so much it worked.. My understanding was we should never use array index as the key.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the array index as the key, 99% of the time that is what you want.  However, if you add/remove/re-order your components then you can get into trouble doing this.  Check out the docs for more information:  https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Got it.. Btw it's also not letting enter the value of 0 in any of the input.

Comment: I updated the example in the codesandbox.  It should allow 0 and empty.  It is a simplified version:  https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-fire-c4if8?file=/src/ProductView.js

Comment: Thanks again.  Works like a charm now.